# Increasing number of outgoing connections

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-services

We have a cluster of window services that acts as a "hub".  These services will consume a number of 3rd party web services.  Currently we have `maxConnection` set to 20.  However, there are times when the services are handling more then 20 concurrent requests each and any calls to external web services will be dropped.

Is there anything we need to look out for if we increase this number?  What would be the maximum number that we can set safely?

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="20" />
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Edit:  Due to the nature of the system, we cannot use queues to management the requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft recommends 12 * n where n is the number of processors, however you should consider configuring more parameters.  This KB article is a good starting point:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268

Comment: This article refers to an ASP.NET application.  Does this apply to window services as well?

Comment: Yes, as related to the system.net/connectionManagement options in particular.  I've actually gone 20 per proc (MS numbers are conservative). While the CPU utlization has gone up a little overall, performance has multiplied.

Comment: Silly question... I assume that would affect outgoing calls to a WCF service over an HTTP binding.  Also, does the WinINet registry setting have anything to do with this as well?